# Cakephp Current Stable version

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-2.3

I have  some experience with CakePhp 1.3 , i did  one project in 1.3 platform. After that there are new versions of CakePhp are released. now i am confused about developing in which version.. if anybody can assist me about choosing the version. ?

Comment: Isn't it logical that the latest stable version should be the best one?

Comment: Use the latest version, no question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The latest version, usually. It does mean you’ll have to read the manual on differences between 1.x and 2.x, new features etc.

Comment: i have experience in cakephp 1.3, with that experience can i start a new project in cakephp 2.X , if is there iany difficuties how can i overcome that

Comment: I just told you: you’ll have to read the documentation on the differences between 1.x and 2.x.

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of changes in cakephp version 2. I suggest you to start learning 2nd version from documentation http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/index.html .Once you learn basics of new version you can start with it developing